Help Understanding Op-Amp Mixing of Square Waves Swinging from 0V to 9V
I have the following schematic:
In it, U3.1 and U4.1 are two square wave oscillators that swing between 0V and 9V.
The op-amp U1.1 is configured as an inverting mixer with a gain of 1, since the feedback resistor and the input resistor both have the same value of 1MΩ.
I understand that the op-amp will do whatever it can to keep both inputs the same. If pin 3 of the op-amp is at 4.5V (Vcc/2), then the inverting input (pin 2) must also be at 4.5V. Up to this point, I think I have it right, correct?
So, if both inputs are the same, does that mean the op-amp output must be -4.5V? If so, I don't understand how the output can be -4.5V when I'm using a power supply that only provides between 0V and 9V. Where does this -4.5V at the output come from?
A detailed analysis of the circuit would be greatly appreciated.


Where did you find the schematic? You've provided zero context and the circuit demands a context. The two schmitt trigger oscillators are set to similar, but not exactly the same, frequencies and will start up with random phase, as well. The output of the opamp decidedly will not reach -4.5 V. Where did you get that? It's just not possible. And the mixer will sweep through weird staircasing behavior with frequency beats. It also likely requires another part or two, I imagine. So again, what's the context? Where did this come from?

I wrote this schematics. it is suppose to active mixing of two or more oscillators (40106)

I had hoped, in asking, that this schematic may have had a source which provided an explanation of the surrounding purpose and its function within that purpose. But you are the source. So that hope is dashed. You've also added nothing to help me see what you see. So I guess others get the honor and privilege of considering your question, further.

this schematics is my try to mix few ( 2 is shown ) square waves oscillators from the 40106 IC using active mixer in inverting configuration instead of just passive mixing.

The idea of "mixing" is already stated in your question title. It is now stated twice in comments. Repeating yourself doesn't help me see any better. Only writing more would do that.

There are no power supply connections shown for the gate package. I'll assume it's 9V Vdd and 0V GND but if that assumption is wrong the conclusions also will be wrong.
There are 4 possibilities for the gate outputs logically 00/01/10/11. In this case, 01 and 10 will lead to the same output.
In the case of 01 and 10 the op-amp will output about 4.5V (op-amp is balanced)
In the case of 00 the op-amp will rail at the positive limit, so probably 7.5V or so at the output (to balance at 13.5V it would need a positive supply of 15V or better, preferably a volt or two more).
In the case of 11 the op-amp will rail at the lower limit, so probably 1.5V or so at the output (to balance at -4.5V it would need a negative supply of -6V at least, preferably a volt or two more).
The op-amp is not really doing much here. You could get a similar effect more efficiently by tossing the op-amp in file 13 and using a few resistors directly with the gate outputs. For example, two 200kΩ resistors directly from the gate outputs to the connector will give you +9/4.5/0 and a similar waveform. The op-amp inverts, but the gates are nominally symmetric so the main differences is that the waveform would start high rather than low- and that could be fixed by connecting the capacitors to Vdd or using additional inverters.
As to what happens at the gates- there are two relaxation oscillators that are nominally the same frequency. In reality slight differences due to component tolerances will cause the oscillators to drive apart over time. The effect will be something like this:

The oscillation frequency is poorly controlled because the hysteresis of the CMOS gate is not well specified. The matching is also difficult to predict- the gates will likely be well matched with each other since they are on the same chip, so capacitor tolerances and resistor tolerances will dominate. I would expect frequency tolerance of 20% or more, and matching of maybe a couple % with parts from the same batch and electrolytic capacitors. In practice that means it might take 50 cycles for the two oscillators to get back to where they started wrt each other.

If you've left power supply pins of any IC unconnected in a simulator, there's no guarantee what potentials that IC can or cannot produce, so if you're seeing negative potentials anywhere, in a circuit that has no explicit voltage sources to produce it, that might be the reason.
Secondly, your assumption that U1.1's inverting and non-inverting must have the same potential (+4.5V) is only true if the op-amp output is not saturated against one of the supply rails:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On the left, the op-amp has supplies that enable its output to swing far enough to produce the correct output:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= 4.5 - (V_A-4.5) - (V_B-4.5) \\ \\
&= 13.5 - (V_A + V_B) \\ \\
&= 13.5 - (9 + 9) \\ \\
&= -4.5 \\ \
\end{aligned}
$$
The op-amp adjusts its output to whatever potential is necessary to equalise its two inputs, and in the left circuit the −4.5V output successfully establishes the expected "virtual +4.5V" at its inverting input, seen on VM2.
On the right, the negative supply is 0V, and the op-amp cannot produce a −4.5V output. It does the best it can though, saturating nearly against the negative supply rail, but it's not low enough to obtain that virtual +4.5V, shown on VM4.
Don't forget that the TL07x series of op-amps cannot produce 0V or +9V outputs, with supplies of 0V and +9V. The datasheet tells us they cannot guarantee outputs closer than 1.5V to either supply, so the best you should expect is an output between +1.5V and +7.5V.

The output of an op-amp cannot swing above or below its supply voltage rails, in this case from 0V to +9V.
If the non-inverting (+) input gets more positive than the inverting (-) input, the output will swing up to the positive supply rail, unless a negative feedback limits it to a lower value.
Likewise, if the (-) input becomes more positive than the (+) input, the output swings in the opposite direction, down to zero volts, if there is no negative feedback to limit the amount of the swing.
The amplification in your op-amp circuit is -1, so the op-amp will simply invert the output of the logic gate and swing as much as the logic gate output swings, in this case rail-to-rail, in other words from 0V to +9V.
The above description is for an ideal op-amp, most real-world op-amps can't swing all the way up or down to the supply rails.
What I don't understand is why use two square waves of the same frequency as inputs?



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. (Top) Both inputs at +9 V. (Bottom) Both inputs at 0 V.

I understand that the op-amp will do whatever it can to keep both inputs the same.

Up to a point. This is true if:

There is negative feedback. (It doesn't apply for an amplifier with no feedback or for a Schmitt trigger with positive feedback.)
The output has not saturated. If it has then it can't apply enough correction and the inverting input will deviate from the virtual ground.


If pin 3 of the op-amp is at 4.5V (Vcc/2), then the inverting input (pin 2) must also be at 4.5V.

Subject to 1 and 2 above.
In Figure 1-top the two inputs are at +9 V so the output should be -4.5 V as you calculated. But the output reaches 0 V and can go no further negative. (There is a slight negative, < 1 mV, in the simulation. This is an error.) As a result you can see that VM2 and VM3 don't match.
Similarly in Figure 1-bottom the inputs are at 0 V so a calculation would suggest that the output should be 13.5 V but that is not possible from a 9 V supply.
Note also that most op-amps can't quite get to the rail voltages. I didn't check the datasheet but I suspect that the TL072 output could probably swing between 1 V - 8 V or so. There are rail-to-rail op-amps which may do better.

Wow that TL072 Circuitlab model is really garbage.

So my assumption that the output should be -4.5V is right but because it can't deliver this value of -4.5V it will output the lowest voltage possible (in this case 0V) ?

With 9V and 0V supplies, the outputs and inputs can't be beyond those limits, and even then, the op-amp inputs and outputs can't go near supply rails, but about 2V less.
You are using a single supply with 4.5V bias so everything must revolve around this bias, maybe down to 2V and up to 7V.
